# siunitx uncertainty values - different number of decimal places (e.g. 98.5 +/- 0.98 %)

Tags: siunitx

I'm using siunitx to report a value plus an 'uncertainty' (as defined in the siunitx package). I'm running into problems with my desired formatting, and I think the issue is because I'd like the resulting uncertainty to have a different number of decimal places than the value that the uncertainty pertains to. E.g. 98.5 (one decimal place) +/- 0.98 (two decimal places). Note that in this example the values have a unit (%) meaning that solutions using `\SI` are preferred over `num`.

Anyone know how to produce something equal to the first attempt below but with the first number (98.5) reported to one decimal place instead of 2?

The context is that I am citing values from a scientific journal article, so regardless of whether a differing number of decimal places is 'correct' I want to accurately reflect the values reported. The 'uncertainty' in this context represents standard deviation about a mean.

Below is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{range-units=single,
        separate-uncertainty = true,
        multi-part-units = single}

\begin{document}

\noindent\SI{98.5 \pm 0.98}{\percent} : Spacing correct, precision wrong (desired 98.5, not 98.50)

\noindent\SIrange[range-phrase=\ \textpm\ ]{98.50}{0.98}{\percent} : Workaround. Note different (wrong) spacing around plus/minus sign

\noindent\ \SIrange[range-phrase=\ \textpm\ ]{98.5}{0.98}{\percent} : Workaround with desired numbers. Incorrect spacing maintained

\noindent\SI{98.5 (98)}{\percent} : Precision correct, uncertainty value wrong.

%\noindent\SI{98.5 (9.8)}{\percent} : Expected to fix uncertainty value of above, returns error instead

\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE]

Comment: As as side note, please keep in mind that **values and uncertainties should really be expressed with the same number of significant digits**. (See eg. [NIST recommendations](https://www.nist.gov/document-100), or §7.2.6 of this [BIPM guide](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/documents/jcgm/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answers proposed by Joseph Wright are viable options, I prefer the workaround I proposed in my original question using `\SIrange` because it preserves the functionality of keeping whether units are repeated or not (`range-units`) as a variable (i.e. A +/- B% vs A% +/- B%).

Thank you to Joseph Wright for confirming that there wasn't a more elegant solution to this problem.

Preferred answer is below, followed by an MWE illustrating the impact of `range-units` on the proposed solutions.

Preferred Answer: `\SIrange[range-phrase=\ \textpm\ ]{98.50}{0.98}{\percent}`

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty = true}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{range-units=single}
Single Units in Setup: \\
\SIrange[range-phrase=\ \textpm\ ]{98.5}{0.98}{\percent} \\
\SI[parse-numbers = false]{98.5 \pm 0.98}{\percent} \\
$98.5 \pm \SI{0.98}{\percent}$ \\

\sisetup{range-units=repeat}
Repeat Units in Setup: \\
\SIrange[range-phrase=\ \textpm\ ]{98.5}{0.98}{\percent}  - Functionality Maintained\\
\SI[parse-numbers = false]{98.5 \pm 0.98}{\percent} - Functionality NOT Maintained\\
$98.5 \pm \SI{0.98}{\percent}$ - Functionality NOT Maintained\\

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE showing effect of range-units on alternative solutions]

Answer (score 9):

There are limits to what one can convince the parsing system to do: where that happens, you'll need to do things manually. Depending on how you want your markup to look, you might go with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers = false]{98.5 \pm 0.98}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
$98.5 \pm \SI{0.98}{\percent}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shucks. Well, thanks for your help just the same!