# siunitx uncertainty values with different number of decimal places and scientific notation

Tags: siunitx

I'm using the siunitx package to typeset number in a table. Because some of the number have an uncertainty value of 1 or 2 I want more decimal places in the uncertainty value than in the number itself, just like here:
[siunitx uncertainty values - different number of decimal places (e.g. 98.5 +/- 0.98 %)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402790/siunitx-uncertainty-values-different-number-of-decimal-places-e-g-98-5-0)

The difference is that I use \num{} and I want to have scientific notation.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[add-decimal-zero, add-integer-zero, separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num[parse-numbers=false]{102.28 \pm 0.095} \\ 
\num[scientific-notation=true]{9.5 \pm 0.16e-4} \\
\num[scientific-notation=true,parse-numbers=false]{9.5 \pm 0.16e-4}
\end{document}
```

The first line works, I get the number of decimal places that I want. The second and third lines do not work. I would like to have: (9.5 ± 0.16)x10^-4
Does anyone have a solution for this perhaps?

Comment: The first two are as you expected. Only the third one is not as you are expecting. right?

Comment: The first two are is as I expect. But there is a problem with the second one, I would like to see: (9.5 ± 0.16)x10^-4 and the second one gives (9.50 ± 0.16)x10^-4

Comment: That is computing the powers of ten and then putting the decimals?

Comment: I tried to solve it with the third one, but then I get 9.5 ± 0.16x10^-4, which makes it look like only the uncertainty is in the order of 10^-4, they should be both.